# cordova.js has no method 'log'

Tags: cordova, console.log

In release mode, I generally disable console.log method with this tiny little code:

```
var consoleHolder = console;
function debug(bool) {
    if (!bool) {
        console = {};
        Object.keys(consoleHolder).forEach(function(key) {
            console[key] = function() {};
        })
    } else {
        console = consoleHolder;
    }
};

debug(false);
```

In my ionic project, build my project with `debug(false)`. It works fine excepts in some of the devices running `Android 4.4.4`. In those devices, following error occurs and the application shows a blank screen.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'log'", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1185)
```

And If I build with `debug(true)`, it works fine.

Comment: your function is probably causing this, if your project is to be compiled for phones, you can just remove the console plugin before compilation. You could also ensure that at least `log` exists in your console object, in case of original console object is missing or anything and that this property is not returned by `Object.keys`

Comment: @Kaddath In my function, I didn't delete any keys, just replaced all console keys with an empty function.

Comment: i never talked about you deleting keys.. But you build your new `console` from an empty object, if for any reason, the initial `console` object is missing or incomplete, there will be nothing in the new one (or as incomplete as the original). I would at least ensure that there is a `log` function in it..